# I want to call a method by calling outer function

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I am currently learning about 'creating objects using the factory pattern' in Javascript. I have written this bit of code. I want to call the `vehicle.getInfo();` function by calling the `getVehicle();` function.

```
function getVehicle (theYear, theMake, theModel) {
    var vehicle = new Object();
        vehicle.year = theYear
        vehicle.make = theMake
        vehicle.model = theModel
        vehicle.getInfo = function () {
           return 'Vehicle: ' + this.year + ' ' + this.make + ' ' + this.model;
           console.log('Vehicle: ' + this.year + ' ' + this.make + ' ' + this.model);
        };
        console.log(vehicle);     // at this level, is there a way to call getInfo function without the actual "console.log(vehicle.getInfo());"
};

getVehicle("2014", "Tata", "Zest");
```

In the `getVehicle()` function, I'd like to console.log what the `vehicle.getInfo()` method returns. But I'd like to do this, without using `console.log(vehicle.getInfo());`.

Is that possible?

Can you please help me?

Comment: If you `return` in your function the following instruction won't be executed. Try to move the `return` statement below the `console.log`.

Comment: OH! So return does not allow further instructions within a function?

Comment: "*is there a way to call getInfo function without the actual call `vehicle.getInfo()`*" - no. Why would there? But more: why would you need this?